# No module named 'mysql' on virtual env

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, virtualenv

Outside the virtual env, it is working fine. But inside the virtual env, the MySQL Python connector is not imported. I am working on the Raspberry Pi. The following shows what I have mentioned. What should I do to fix it?

===========================================================================

## outside the virtual evn (working fine.)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/webapp3 $ python3 vsearch_web.py  
* Running on    http://127.0.0.1:5000/

   127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2017 15:29:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

   127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2017 15:30:17] "POST /search HTTP/1.1" 200 -

   127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2017 15:30:30] "GET /viewlog HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

=========================================================================

## inside the virtual env (producing errors.)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/webapp3 $ source venv/bin/activate

(venv)pi@raspberrypi:~/webapp3 $ python3 vsearch_web.py 

 Traceback (most recent call last):   

 File "vsearch_web.py", 

line 3,
   in <module> from DBcm import UseDatabase    File
   "/home/pi/webapp3/DBcm.py", 

line 1, in <module> import
   mysql.connector 

ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Comment: Access to the system site packages from within the virtual env is probably disabled by the virtual env configuration. E.g. If you have `pyvenv.cfg` file in the virtual env directory, edit it to contain `include-system-site-packages = true`. If you do not have this file, check the documentation for your set of virtual env utilities.

Answer (score 0):

The module isn't installed in the virtual environment yet. Activate the environment and run:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I tried that on, but I end up with the following error.
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-756h92ed/MySQL-python/

Comment: Ah, sorry MySQL-python only works in python2. Try mysqlclient instead. It is a fork for python3. See updated answer.